# Add a character within regular expression so that it show's up on matching value

Tags: regex

So what I'm trying to do is add ":" character into a regular expression so that it come's to the matching value when I'm parsing all the values.

Here's the code that I'm parsing from:

```
<tr>
<td>165.227.124.179</td>
<td>3128</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>13.56.91.112</td>
<td>443</td>
</tr>
```

I need to get the values inside the "td" tags and add ":" between them like so:

```
165.227.124.179:3128
13.56.91.112:443
```

I get both of the values parsed, but what I can't find out is that is it possible to add the ":" character between these 2 values inside the regular expression and not after the matching value is parsed.

I've tried googling it real hard, but I just can't seem to get a right sort of match for the problem I have. Sorry if the question is confusing, I've gotten so confused along the way, feel free to ask a clearance.

Comment: Show your code code please?

Comment: Regex is a read-only (matching) concept. When you _add_ a literal to a regex, it doesn't insert it into a string. You have to create a replacement string from the _parts_ that matched. That's how you _insert_ characters.

Comment: @AlexK. I know, it isn't a good choice for it, but I've seen a couple of these sort of regex expressions before just need to know if it's possible to add the ":" character into a regex expression

Comment: HTML and regex are not good fiends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintenable.

Comment: @sln that explained it, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Regex not recommended to parse html, but if you have to use it something like

Find `<td>(\d+(?:\.\d+)+)</td>\s*<td>(\d+)</td>`
Replace `<td>$1:$2</td>`

https://regex101.com/r/SiOgKy/1